# Python Logic Operators Binary

Tags: python-3.x

I am totally new to programming.
How do I write a Python script to do the following without using bitwise operators, only allow to use logical and or operators. Thanks in advance!
I'm stuck.

& and
Sets result bit to 1 if both corresponding bits are 1.
E.g. 1010 & 1100 is 1000

| or
Sets result bit to 1 if one of the two corresponding bits is 1.
E.g 1010 | 1100 is 1110

^ xor
Sets result bit to 1 only if one of the corresponding bits is 1.
E.g. 1010 ^ 1100 is 0110

Output:
Enter binary expression: 110110 & 110011
Result: 110010

```
expr = input('Enter binary expression:  ')
n1, op, n2 = expr.split()
n1 = int(n1)
n2 = int(n2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f402Q.png)

Comment: This site is not meant to do your homework for you. But here are some hints: 1) don’t use `int` to convert the whole number, you need to convert each digit separately. 2) look up the function `zip`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use the bitwise operators, then probably the most straightforward way would be to go bit by bit and do the comparison yourself. This is easiest to do if we represent them as strings

We don't even need to convert the inputs to integers (which can be done by calling `int(n1, 2)` to specify base-2 instead of base-10), since they're given as strings in binary already. If they were given in base-10, we could read them in as integers and then use the built-in `bin()` method to represent them as binary strings.

Since there's a method `bin()` that can represent an integer as a binary string (prefaced with the characters `0b`, which we can remove by slicing them off), we can use that, compare digits in the string, then convert the result back into an integer.

```
expr = input('Enter binary expression:  ')  # sample: enter "110110 & 110011"
n1, op, n2 = expr.split()
# -------------
result = ''
for (c1, c2) in zip(n1, n2):
    next_bit = ""
    if op == "&":
        next_bit = "1" if (c1 == "1" and c2 == "1") else "0"
    elif op == "|":
        next_bit = "1" if (c1 == "1" or c2 == "1") else "0"
    elif op == "^":
        next_bit = "1" if (c1 != c2) else "0"
    result += next_bit

print(result)
# 110010
```

This isn't the *most* efficient way (you can do some complicated iterative arithmetic and treat the numbers as integers, instead of treating them as strings and just comparing digit by digit), but it's probably the most straightforward and easiest to understand, especially given how the numbers are inputted here.